# Using jQuery .append and .html together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having to add content dynamically to an iFrame that is generated by my CMS in their forum module. I have no control over the HTML. I am adding content dynamically and trying to find the best solution.

Here is the code I am using:

***HTML***

```
<iframe id="re_contentIframe">
 <html>
  <body>
   <p>Forum content is typed here.</p>
   <p>More forum content.</p>
    Forum Signature
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

***JS***

```
nestedFrame = myFrame.find('#re_contentIframe').contents().find('body');
nestedFrame.append("Dynamic content" + data); //this is what is inserted dynamically.
```

Here is the issue I run into. Because I cannot control the code for the iFrame my CMS generates because of this I end up having something like this when I use the above code:

```
Forum Signature Dynamic content...
```

I want the dynamic content to be added *below* the `Forum Signature`. I then tired this:

```
nestedFrame.html("Dynamic content" + data); //this is what is inserted dynamically.
```

When I do this the forum content is wiped by `.html`

I then tried this:

```
nestedFrame.append(" <br> Dynamic content" + data);
```

When I do that it prints the `<br>`.

Here is my question:

Is there a way to append html to the target without wiping the html that is there? I cannot figure a way to do this.

Comment: Try `nestedFrame.append($.parseHTML(" <br> Dynamic content" + data));` or unwrapping and using `inserAdjacentHTML()`

Comment: @megawac - the `$.parseHTML` worked. Please post as an answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jQuery.parseHTML(str)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) converts the passed string to the actual html contents (including textNodes) whereas just calling `$(str)` will only return the elements in the string.

So where

```
$(" <br> Dynamic content" + data) //=> <br>

$.parseHTML(" <br> Dynamic content" + data) // textNode + <br> + textNode
```

When you're appending the string, as I mentioned in the comment, you can also just use `insertAdjacentHTML`

`nestedFrame[0].insertAdjacentHTML(" <br> Dynamic content" + data);` which should do the same as `nestedFrame.append($.parseHTML(" <br> Dynamic content" + data));`

Answer (score 0):

There is a few options

1. You can create element -> `var br = document.createElement('br');` and append them
2. Use `'<br>'` inside, With + + in between, not 100% sure of that method.
3. You can checkout j[Query after](http://api.jquery.com/after/), wonderful solution for that issues.

Goodluck.